# How to display the suggestion for autocomplete field using json file?

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, autocompletetextview

I have this json that has " product code" inside this product code has another jsonobject and string.

What I want is that when I input the "product code" the suggested description will show.

I already get the display for suggested description when I input the product description code but it seems that it displaying in wrong way.

What I mean is that when I type the "product code" "BI" the display for suggested description is like this

{"GNT": "GIANT","TRL": "TREEK","CNN": "CNDALE","ST": "SANTA","SCT": "SCOTT"}

here is my json

```
{
    "BI": {
        "desc": {
            "MBIK": "MOUNTAIN BIKE",
            "FBIK": "FOLDING BIKE",
            "EBIK": "E-BIKE",
            "OTHER": "OTHER"
        },
        "brand": {
            "GNT": "GIANT",
            "TRL": "TREEK",
            "CNN": "CNDALE",
            "STC": "SANTA",
            "SCT": "SCOTT"
        },
        "category": "BICYCLE & EBIKE STORE"
    },
    "CA": {
        "desc": {
            "CARA": "CAR AUDIO",
            "CARS": "CAR SPEAKER",
            "TIRE": "CAR TIRE",
            "OTHER": "OTHER"
        },
        "brand": {
            "AIC": "AICHI",
            "BRI": "BRIGDESTONE",
            "CON": "CONTINENTAL",
            "DUN": "DUNLOP",
            "FAL": "FALKEN GR"
        }
                "category": "CAR ACCESORIES"
    }, 
        and so on.. { 
                    }
}
```

here is the my code to parse my json to my fragment

```java
private void loadLookupCategoryJson() {

        mLookupProducts = new ArrayList<>();
        mArrayStringLookupProduct = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(loadLookupBrandJSON());
            Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();

            while(keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) json.get(key);

                JSONObject brand = obj.getJSONObject(Keys.CATEGORY_BRAND);
                JSONObject desc =  obj.getJSONObject(Keys.CATEGORY_DESC);
                String category = obj.getString(Keys.CATEGORY);

                LookupProducts lookupProduct = new LookupProducts(key, brand, desc, category);
                mLookupProducts.add(lookupProduct);
                mArrayStringLookupProduct.add(String.valueOf(brand));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and here is my to get the brand dynamic field

```java
} else if (format.equalsIgnoreCase(Keys.AUTO_COMPLETE_FIELD)) {
 addTextViews(title);
 addAutoCompleteField(desc, inputType, title, mKeys.get(i), mArrayStringLookupProduct, maxLength, minLength);
}
```

I expect the output should be like this

INPUT TEXT: T

SUGGESTED DISPLAY:GIANT
                  TREEK
                  SANTA
                  SCOTT

Display all values with "T"

actual output

INPUT TEXT: BI

SUGGESTED DISPLAY:{"GNT": "GIANT","TRL": "TREEK","CNN": "CNDALE","ST": "SANTA","SCT": "SCOTT"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In this line of code -  *mArrayStringLookupProduct.add(String.valueOf(brand));*
   You are adding whole jsonObject into mArrayStringLookupProduct ArrayList.
2. You only want JSONObject brand's values in this ArrayList.

You can make the following changes-

```java
   JSONObject brand = obj.getJSONObject(Keys.CATEGORY_BRAND);
   JSONObject desc =  obj.getJSONObject(Keys.CATEGORY_DESC);
   String category = obj.getString(Keys.CATEGORY);
   lookupProduct = new LookupProducts(key, brand, desc, category);
   mLookupProducts.add(lookupProduct);

   // iterate every brand key, fetch its value and add in arrayList
   Iterator<String> brandKeys = brand.keys();
   while(brandKeys.hasNext()) {
        String bKey = brandKeys.next();
        mArrayStringLookupProduct.add((String) brand.get(bKey));
   }
```

Comment: I got an error with the "values" in this code mArrayStringLookupProduct.addAll(brand.values());

Comment: i had used org.json.simple library which had values() method for jsonObject but the logic is still same. You only need values of brand. Iterate over the keys of jsonObject brand, fetch its values and store into arrayList.

Comment: I am glad i was able to help.